# Function to identify changes done previously

Tags: r, list, functional-programming

**BACKGROUND**

I have a list of 16 data frames. A data frame in it looks like this. All the other data frames have the similar format. `DateTime` column is of `Date class`  while `Value` column is of `time series` class

```
> head(train_data[[1]])

    DateTime Value
739 2009-07-31  49.9
740 2009-08-31  53.5
741 2009-09-30  54.4
742 2009-10-31  56.0
743 2009-11-30  54.4
744 2009-12-31  55.3
```

I am performing forecasting for the `Value` column across all the `data.frames` in this `list` . The following line of code feeds data into UCM model.

```
train_dataucm <- lapply(train_data, transform, Value = ifelse(Value > 50000 , Value/100000 , Value ))
```

The transform function is used to reduce large values because UCM has some issues rounding off large values ( I don't know why though ). I just understood that from user @KRC in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335049/using-ucm-function-from-rucm-package)

One data frame got affected because it had large values which got transformed to log values. All the other dataframes remained unaffected.

```
> head(train_data[[5]])
      DateTime  Value
715 2009-07-31 139901
716 2009-08-31 139492
717 2009-09-30 138818
718 2009-10-31 138432
719 2009-11-30 138659
720 2009-12-31 138013
```

I got to know this because I manually checked each one of the 15 data frames

**PROBLEM**

1. Is there any function which can call out the data frames which got
   affected due to the condition which I inserted?
2. The function must be able to list down the data frames which got affected and should be able to put them into a list.

If I will be able to do this, then I can apply anti log function on the values and get the actual values.

This way I can give the correct forecasts with minimal human intervention.

I hope I am clear in specifying the problem .

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check whether any of your values in a data frame is too high:

```
has_too_high_values = function (df)
    any(df$Value > 50000)
```

And then collect them, e.g. using `Filter`:

```
Filter(has_too_high_values, train_data)
```